# Is there a bundle for ionic 2 that I can use in js fiddle ?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, bundle, cdn

The link I have here is to a list of ionic bundles that I can use place in 
external resources in js.fiddle:

http://code.ionicframework.com/#

However none of these seem to be for ionic 2, only ionic 1. 
My googling didn't turn up any CDN explicitly for ionic 2... Any ideas where I can find it? Or will one of the resources from that list suffice?

Comment: why js.fiddle? Could it be a *plunker* instead?

Comment: @sebaferreras yes it could be plunkr

Comment: Great, @FernadoDelOlmo already added a plunker, so I guess you can mark his answer as the accepted answer and we can close the issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the link to a plunker with ionic 3.3.0 loaded to make demos:

```
plnkr.co/edit/sEuwPG?p=options
```

Hope this helps you